# How to push changes to branch?

Tags: git, github

Can you explain me how to use git in case, when I have access to repository:

- How to download repository
- How to push changes in selected branch
- How to select branch to push

I tried these steps

```
git init
git clone git.repository
git pull develop  (where develop is branch)
git add .
git commit -m "m"
git push origin develop
```

Result is:

```
* branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How to download repository

```
# download a repository
git clone <url>
```

> How to push changes in selected branch

```
# push changes to remote branch
# assuming you are on the master branch right now
git push origin master
```

> How to select branch to push

```
 # push any desired branch to remote
 git push -u origin local_branch_name:remote_branch_name
```

Comment: You push in master, and how to set branch after clone?

Comment: When I tr push I get: error: src refspec develop does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:ValTrading.git'

Comment: if you dont have the remote branch so checkout the local branch to any desired name and than simply push it. `git checkout -b b1 && git push origin b1`

Comment: I dont need to create a new branch, I need to push in exist

Comment: so you need to be on this branch in order to push it if its not already in the remote repo

Comment: Can you move to chat please?

Answer (score 40):

### 3 Steps to Commit your changes

Suppose you have created a new branch on GitHub with the name **feature-branch**.

[image]

**FETCH**

```
    git pull --all         Pull all remote branches
    git branch -a          List all branches now
```

Checkout and switch to the feature-branch directory. You can simply copy the branch name from the output of branch -a command above

> **`git checkout -b feature-branch`**

**VALIDATE**

Next use the git branch command to see the current branch. It will show feature-branch with * In front of it

```
git branch   check current branch
git status   check the state of your codebase
```

**COMMIT**

```
git add .   add all untracked files
git commit -m "Rafactore code or use your message"
```

Take update and the push changes on the origin server

```
 git pull origin feature-branch
 git push origin feature-branch
```

OR you can rebase with the master before commit

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
git push origin feature-branch
```

Answer (score 3):

First i would like to suggest you to read this nice [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs).

**Prerequirements**:
- Installed git.
- Have access to the repository.

1. You can download repository following these commands:
   `git clone <depositry https or ssh link>`
2. First you need to add changes, create commit, add remote branch and then push.
   `git remote add <repo name> <repo url>` 
   *Example if you use BitBucket:* git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org//.git  
   `git status // to see all changes (they should be printed with red` color)
   `git add <file name> // add the file as git staged`
   `git commit or git commit -m 'some message'`
   `git push <remote name> <branch name>`

Comment: git remote add <repo name> <repo url>  whee repo name is?

Comment: When I did clone it downloaded files, but onlt git directory

Comment: Here is a example if you use bitbucket: git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<project>/<gitrepo>.git

Comment: Ok, in that case your link will look like this: git remote add origin https://github.com/<YourUserName>/<RepositoryName>.git

Comment: bwm,when you create new repository on GitHub, BitBucket, GitLab and etc. you will get instructions how to init git, what is the remote branch url and etc.

Comment: In that case you already have added remote branch if you have cloned repository. You can check it using command: git remote -v

Comment: it returns: develop git@github.com:Trading.git (push)

Comment: Ok then you have remote branch. So next step would be to push your local changes (commit) to the remote repository, but you can push commit only if you have rights to do so. Or you can fork project and then clone it and push

Comment: I tried: `e:\abs\test>git push origin develop
error: src refspec develop does not match any.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138157/discussion-between-darama-and-milannz).