# Git - Adding more changes to an old commit

Tags: bitbucket, git-commit, git-amend, git

I have a git branch called 'AAA'. I made my initial commit & created a pull request of this branch yesterday. But today after reviewing comments, I have to do some changes to my code.

I done the changes. Then I looked at remote repository commit list and I found one new commit has been done.

So how can I commit my new changes to the remote branch. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Just commit and push. Your new commit automatically becomes part of the same pull request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to push changes to branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820840/how-to-push-changes-to-branch)

Answer (score 1):

First of all check, you are on the right branch using `git branch` command, then follow below steps:

1. take pull from the same branch:

   `git pull origin <your-branch-name>`
2. Then add files for commit & put a commit message:

   `git add .` & `git commit -m "<your-commit-message>"`
3. Push the changes on your branch:

   `git push origin <your-branch-name>`